# How do you upload a file to a restful web service in java?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven, jax-rs

I am rather new to building REST web services in java (built several in the .NET world) and I am running into an issue that my google-fu is not turning up an answer too. I have a post method:

```
@POST
@Consumes(value = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response postFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream content,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
    String fileName = fileDetail.getName();
    String ext = getFileExtension(fileName);
    URI uri = context.getBaseUri();

    UUID userId = processData.SubmitData(content, ext);

    return Response.created(URI.create(uri + "/api/appuser/" + userId)).build();
}
```

that is returning as 404 when I try to post to it. I am using the most current versions of Jax-rs, glass fish, et al.

my web.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>ScoringApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Scoring Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <!-- Enable Tracing support. -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.tracing</param-name>
            <param-value>ALL</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.scoringapp.api</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
           <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
           <param-value>com.scoringapp.api.MyApplication</param-value>
       </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Scoring Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And my Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        // register resources and features
        classes.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
        classes.add(FileResource.class);
        classes.add(LoggingFilter.class);
        classes.add(CORSResponseFilter.class);
        classes.add(CORSRequestFilter.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

anything else to help me solve this would be great.
(running this in Maven, using a dynamic web app, I followed tutorials :) There are a couple of other test endpoints that do work fine, so I know I am getting access to it and hitting the base url returns he index.html that I created just to be sure everything is there.)

Comment: Your file upload code is right. Please check if you are using the correct URL to access the resource  .

Comment: Yup, my url was wrong. Got a little too used to IIS and its fancy case insensitive urls. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my issue was not following HTML specs correctly and watching my URI casing. my bad...